# Solve an equation with functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to solve a simple problem on projecteuler.net, the $25$.

The goal is to obtain the first number from the Fibonacci sequence that contains $4$ digits.

I have done the following : 
Implementing the Binet's Fibonacci number formula in order to find the nth number from Fibonacci. So I can use this equation to find the first number that contains $4$ digits :

$  \text{Round}(\log(\text{Fibonacci}(x))) = 1000 $

The fibonnaci function is defined like that : 
$ \text{Fibonnaci}(x) = \frac{\varphi^x-(-\varphi)^{-x}}{\sqrt{5}} $

So now, I'm struggling because I don't know how to solve an equation with some functions in it. I tried to break down the function in the equation like this :

$$ \text{Round}(\log \dfrac{\varphi^x-(-\varphi)^{-x}}{\sqrt{5}}) = 1000 $$

Two problems: I don't know how to break down $\log$ and $\text{Round}$ function, and the second, I'm wondering if there is a better solution to solve an equation with functions than breaking down all functions in the equation. I hope you guys understood me, I'm not really good at maths, that's why I'm training.
I know there was some simpler way to resolve this Euler problem but I want to achieve it that way, so I can learn a lot of things.
Thank you :)

Comment: Since you're taking the log on one side, you need to do it on the other.  Replace $1000$ by $3$.  I would punt the "round" function and make this an inequality.

Answer (score 2):

For large $n$ we can just take
$$F_n\approx \frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^n$$
where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. For the Fibonacci number to contain $4$ digits we need
$$F_n\ge1000$$
Which we can approximate using
$$ \frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^n\ge1000$$
$$ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^n\ge1000\sqrt{5}$$
$$ n\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)}\ge\ln{(1000\sqrt{5})}$$
$$n\ge \frac{\ln{(1000\sqrt{5})}}{\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)}}$$
$$n\ge16.027\dots$$
$$\therefore n=17$$
is the minimum such value of $n$.